# What shrub is this?

Tags: shrubs

I have got this shrub and I have no clue what it this plant (Fruit or Flower or what). Any ideas? Looks to me like a perennial green shrub. Location is Sydney, Australia.[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm unconvinced this is blueberry - still checking to see what else it could be, but not sure you should eat the berries without 100% certainty...

Comment: Just a wild guess, could it be some kind of Holly?

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm, It does not have the characteristic spikes on leaves edges.

Comment: I agree that this could very well be a holly. Try looking up Ilex decidua and comparing details. Have the fruits yet changed colour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your blueberry plant is looking a lot better then mine!

Edit: as bamboo says this is probably not a blueberry after all.

The calyx end of a blueberry forms an indented perfect 5 point star, and your berries are flat.

The lilac color looks good.

Your leaves are also widely serrated, but the serrations on my plants are very fine, and are more easily felt then seen.

The leaves are alternating on a brown stem with no thorns as they should but I think one should see vegetative budding at the base of the leaves by late summer, early autumn.

One might also expect to see a little red in the leafs.

I guess if the berries don't turn blue you have your answer.

Comment: Thanks. Never crossed my mind even when I have so many blueberries in Supermarkets!!